# Microsoft Access 2003 .mdb to MSSQL and Access 2013 - User security & experience

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

Microsoft Access 2013 contains ability to link program (desktop) with MSSQL backend.

Can you clarify some moments here:

1. Can i grant some users read/write rights to my data in SQL database (or i need to ask my IT-depart)?
2. Can users with Access 2007 use my new SQL database?
3. Can i use all of mine queries / forms from Access 2013 with my new SQL backend?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can link you Sql server to access by going external database tab select ODBC database and select link database option.

Select Machine Data sources tab and click new

click next and select Sql server
 and enter server details and select the tables to link

So now it can be able to create forms for data entry in ms access directly to the sql server with Sql lo-gin

it can manage the lo-gins and permissions to the tables for users through SMSS.